# (cs50)not getting output for the given code. can anyone please check this out?

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50, c-strings, continue

my code counts the number of letters from the given string(excluding white space). cs50.h is a library which consists of `get_string()` function which takes input from user. the code is compiling but when i give an input which has more than one word, it stops working(doesn't give me anything).can anyone please tell why?(i am using c language)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_letters(string text);

int main(void)
{
    string input = get_string("Text: ");
    int letters = count_letters(input);
    printf("%i\n",letters);
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(text[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(isspace(text[i]))
            continue;

        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: For a start, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, what programming language are you using? [edit] your Q to remove the tag that's not that language. Next time, also make sure you read the description of the tags you apply!

Comment: Show the code for `get_string`.  Also, are you using C or C++?

Comment: This would have been a great time to learn [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite while loop when the entered string contains a white space character

```
int count_letters(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(text[i] != '\0')
    {

        if(isspace(text[i]))
            continue;

        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

because when a white space character is encountered the variable i is not incremented due to the `continue` statement.

Rewrite the function for example like

```
int count_letters(string text)
{
    int count = 0;

    for ( ; *text != '\0'; ++text )
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )*text ) )
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Pay attention to that it will be much better if instead of the typedef name `string` as the parameter type specifier you will use the specifier `const char *` as for example

```
int count_letters( const char *text);
```

because the passed string is not changed within the function.

And instead of the return type `int` it is better to use the type `size_t`.

So the function can be declared and defined like

```
size_t count_letters( const char *text )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( ; *text != '\0'; ++text )
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )*text ) )
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

And in main the function is called like

```
char *input = get_string("Text: ");
size_t letters = count_letters(input);
printf("%zu\n",letters);
```

Comment: `text` is a string not a char*

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if(isspace(text[i]))
   continue;
```

means if the character at offset `i` of `text` is a space `continue`.

But continue means go back to the loop condition so `i++;` won't get executed.

So if your text includes a space your code gets stuck in a non-terminating loop checking the same space character over and over again.

Comment: Yahh..got it..thats why my code was in a non terminating loop..thankss i will modify it as needed.